# Calling another program in a shell script and using the returned data

Tags: shell

I have a c program named calculate which sorts out the correct data

Data input (initial file.txt):

```
abcd!1023!92
ckdw!3251!io
efgh!9873!xk
```

Data returned:

```
abcd!1023!92
efgh!9873!xk
```

My shell script contains:

```
./calculate | awk -F '!' '{sum += $2} END{print sum}' "$1"
```

When I run the script ./check file.txt it ignores the values returned from the calculate function and instead calculates from the input file.

How do I fix this so that the "awk" function works from the data returned from the ./test function?

Comment: Make sure you don't name your test scripts as 'test'.  On linux, 'test' in an existing program, and if you forget to use ./ then you might wonder what's wrong.

Comment: @Deanie it was actually called calculate just tried to rush the unimportant parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a file to the `awk` script as well as input.

```
./calculate | awk -F '!' '{sum += $2} END{print sum}' "$1"
```

`awk` only uses one or the other and it prefers file arguments when given.

Drop the `"$1"` bit from there.

Answer (score 1):

I did my try.

sorting.sh (my version of your filtering program)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
egrep 'a|e' input.txt
```

program.sh (your shell command)

```
./program.sh | awk -F '!' '{sum += $2} END{print sum}'
```

@Updated, deleted `"$1"` as stated by Etan Reisner

Comment: Stick that pipeline in a script and pass the input file as an argument to the script and you'll see the problem.

Comment: @josegomezr my program was working. I just removed the "$1" like the other answer indicated and it seems to work fine!